# Let's share our emacs php configs

Tags: php, emacs, php-mode

I'm pretty new to `emacs` and I think it would be nice if you share your config that you use in your everyday php work.

Comment: why it has been treated as "offtopic"? the configuration aspect is very close to development itself, some kind of good/best practices, imho. isn't it?

Comment: This question should not have been down-voted.  perhaps the question could be rephrased a little, because I expect there aren't many people with a PHP only emacs config. But to downvote the question without a comment is just rude.

Comment: how to rephrase? to move into general configs without php specifics?

Comment: The default place to share and discuss Emacs configurations should be http://www.emacswiki.org/.

Comment: @Thomas Kappler: well, then the default place to discuss any `.net` quesitons should be social.msdn.microsoft.com. Say this to SO owners, please.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. I don't know .net, but I know the Emacs world, and it's simply a fact that emacswiki is the main hub of the community. That's all I wanted to say - that you might get better results going there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's enough for me, just indentation rules for some project based on kohana:

```
(add-hook 'php-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (c-set-style "bsd")
            (setq c-indent-level 2)
            (setq c-continued-statement-offset 2)
            (setq c-brace-offset -2)
            (setq c-argdecl-indent 0)
            (setq c-label-offset -2)
            (setq c-basic-offset 2)
            (setq tab-width 2)
            (setq indent-tabs-mode nil)
            (c-set-offset 'case-label '+)
            (c-set-offset 'arglist-close 'c-lineup-arglist-operators)
            (c-set-offset 'arglist-intro '+)
            (c-set-offset 'arglist-cont-nonempty 'c-lineup-math)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I lifted some of this from the Emacs configuration discussion on drupal.org. I notice that someone posted a proper derived drupal-mode there, but I've not gotten around to changing my config.

You'll notice that some of this is commented out for being broken. I haven't looked into any of that recently, so I'm just posting it all verbatim.

my-programming.el (which is required by my init.el file)

```
;; nXHTML
(load "nxhtml/autostart.el")

;; ...

;; PHP (see my-php.el)
(autoload 'php-mode "my-php" "PHP Mode." t)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.php[34]?\\'\\|\\.phtml\\'" . php-mode))
;; Drupal mode
(autoload 'drupal-mode "my-php" "Drupal Mode." t)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.\\(module\\|test\\|install\\|theme\\)\\'" . drupal-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("/drupal.*\\.\\(php\\|inc\\)\\'" . drupal-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.info\\'" . conf-windows-mode))
```

my-php.el:

```
;; n.b. php-mode is the modified version provided by nxhtml
;; at: lisp/nxhtml/related/php-mode.el. lisp/nxhtml/related
;; was added to the load path by nxhtml/autostart.el (which
;; is loaded in my-programming.el prior to defining the PHP
;; autoloads).
(load "php-mode") ;load the real php-mode

;; Custom php-mode configuration
(add-hook 'php-mode-hook 'my-php-mode)

(defconst my-php-style
  '((c-offsets-alist . ((arglist-close . c-lineup-close-paren))))
  "My PHP programming style")
(c-add-style "my-php-style" my-php-style)

;; Configure imenu usage with php-imenu (also provided by nxhtml)
(autoload 'php-imenu-create-index "php-imenu" nil t)

(defun my-php-mode ()
  "My php-mode customisations."
  (c-set-style "my-php-style")

  ;; The electric flag (toggled by `c-toggle-electric-state').
  ;; If t, electric actions (like automatic reindentation, and (if
  ;; c-auto-newline is also set) auto newlining) will happen when an
  ;; electric key like `{' is pressed (or an electric keyword like
  ;; `else').
  (setq c-electric-flag nil)
  ;; electric behaviours appear to be bad/unwanted in php-mode

  ;; This is bugging out recently. Not sure why. Thought it
  ;; was a conflict with (my-coding-config), but not certain
  ;; any longer. Commenting out for now.
  ;; Configure imenu
  ;; (php-imenu-setup)

  ;; Find documentation online
  (local-set-key (kbd "<f1>") 'my-php-symbol-lookup))

(defun php-imenu-setup ()
  (setq imenu-create-index-function (function php-imenu-create-index))
  ;; uncomment if you prefer speedbar:
  ;;(setq php-imenu-alist-postprocessor (function reverse))
  (imenu-add-menubar-index))

(defun my-php-symbol-lookup ()
  "Find the symbol at point in the online PHP documentation."
  (interactive)
  (let ((symbol (symbol-at-point)))
    (if (not symbol)
        (message "No symbol at point.")
      (browse-url (concat "http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern="
                          (symbol-name symbol))))))

(defun drupal-mode ()
  "PHP mode configured for Drupal development."
  (interactive)
  (php-mode)
  (message "Drupal mode activated.")
  (set 'tab-width 2)
  (set 'c-basic-offset 2)
  (set 'indent-tabs-mode nil)
  (c-set-offset 'case-label '+)
  (c-set-offset 'arglist-intro '+) ; for FAPI arrays and DBTNG
  (c-set-offset 'arglist-cont-nonempty 'c-lineup-math) ; for DBTNG fields and values

  ;; Don't clobber (too badly) doxygen comments when using fill-paragraph
  (setq paragraph-start (concat paragraph-start "\\| \\* @[a-z]+")
        paragraph-separate "$"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check out my config here:

http://github.com/openist/drupal-emacs

I'm a full time Drupal Developer.